# Surprising UTC offset reported by System.DateTimeOffset instances for dates before 19 Nov 1883

Tags: datetime, .net-core, timezone, utc, datetimeoffset

Note: For convenience, PowerShell is used to demonstrate the behavior, but the question is about the behavior of the [`System.DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset) .NET type.

Note: As [Matt Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson) points out, the behavior in question **only happens on *Unix-like platforms*** (macOS, Linux, using .NET Core).

Seemingly, when `System.DateTimeOffset` converts a local date, the resulting **time-zone offset (offset from UTC) differs for dates before 19 Nov 1883**.

Consider the following PowerShell command:

```
([datetime] '1883-11-18'), ([datetime] '1883-11-19') |
  ForEach-Object { ([datetimeoffset] $_).Offset.ToString() }
```

which, when invoked in the [Eastern Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) yields:

```
-04:57:00
-05:00:00
```

(DST (daylight-saving time) didn't come into play until 1918.)

I suspect that this is related to the following, excerpted [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Meridian_Conference), emphasis added:

> [...] had brought the US railway companies to an agreement which led to **standard railway time** being introduced at **noon on 18 November 1883** across the nation.

- Can anyone confirm this and provide more information?
- Why, specifically, did the offset change by 3 minutes?

[Searching for `1883` in the entire .NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/index?search=1883&scope=.NET) yields just the following, [passing reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/saving-and-restoring-time-zones):

> [...] the U.S. Eastern Standard Time zone from 1883 to 1917, before the introduction of daylight saving time in the United States

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running on Unix-like platforms (Linux, OSX, etc.), the time zone data in the operating system originates from the [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).  Early dates in this data set are referenced by their Local Mean Time (LMT), which is calculated from the latitude and longitude of the reference city.  In this case, US Eastern Time being represented by `America/New_York` has an LMT entry that aligns with your reported findings.

From the [tzdb](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2018e/northamerica#L332-L337):

```
# Zone  NAME              GMTOFF    RULES  FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone    America/New_York  -4:56:02  -      LMT     1883 Nov 18 12:03:58
                          -5:00     US     E%sT    1920
                          -5:00     NYC    E%sT    1942
                          -5:00     US     E%sT    1946
                          -5:00     NYC    E%sT    1967
                          -5:00     US     E%sT
```

Note that seconds in the offset are truncated on import due to the precision of offsets supported by `DateTimeOffset`.

You can read more about LMT (and lots more) in [the theory file](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/theory.html) in the tz database.

On Windows, you would not see this behavior, because Windows doesn't have time zone data for the `Eastern Standard Time` time zone earlier than the 2006-2007 transition. Thus dates earlier than 1987 may be converted incorrectly.  If that matters to you, you'll need another source of time zone information, such as the copy of tzdb included with [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org).

Also note that local time is implied with casting from `DateTime` to `DateTimeOffset`, but only when the input value's `.Kind` is `DateTimeKind.Local` or `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  If instead it's `DateTimeKind.Utc`, then the resulting `DateTimeOffset` will have a zero offset.

Comment: Great stuff, thanks. When you say _truncate_, did you mean rounding up (in terms of absolute value) to the next second? I don't understand how `-4:56:02` turns into `-04:57`.

Comment: Probably.  I'll have to check the implementation.

Comment: "Truncate" in computer languages often means "round towards zero".  It is what the underlying hardware usually does.

Comment: Following up on the truncate/round discussion, the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/91bd5a6a36be3949b879793cfca914e666d89845/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/TimeZoneInfo.Unix.cs#L83-L88), which shows truncation.  However I too get a rounded answer in my testing.  I think it's due to the various negations and additions being done elsewhere in this class, but haven't traced it exactly to why.  Anyway, it's all there if you want to look for yourself.  Cheers!